# Помогите распараллелить функцию медианной фильтрации через OpenMP

Tags: c++, visual-studio, сортировка, openmp

Пожалуйста помогите. Мне нужно 2 рабочих варианта распараллеливания функции медианной фильтрации изображения через OpenMP. (Сами сортировочные функции работают корректно)

```
double MedianFilterBMP(RGBTRIPLE** rgb_in, RGBTRIPLE** rgb_out, int Width, int Height, int RW, int RH, int theards = 1) {
    double time_start = omp_get_wtime();

    int size = ((RH * 2) + 1) * ((RW * 2) + 1);

    // Зарезервируйте память для массивов фильтрации.
    unsigned char* MEDMAS_R = new unsigned char[size];
    unsigned char* MEDMAS_G = new unsigned char[size];
    unsigned char* MEDMAS_B = new unsigned char[size];

    

        // Перебираете изображение с шагом 1.
    for (int Y = 0; Y < Height; Y++) {
        for (int X = 0; X < Width; X++) {
            int index = 0;

            // Перебираете окно вокруг пикселя для апертуры фильтра медианы.
            for (int DY = -RH; DY <= RH; DY++) {
                int KY = Y + DY;

                // Проверьте, находится ли Y в пределах изображения.
                if (KY < 0) KY = 0;
                if (KY > Height - 1) KY = Height - 1;

                for (int DX = -RW; DX <= RW; DX++) {
                    int KX = X + DX;

                    // Проверьте, находится ли X в пределах изображения.
                    if (KX < 0) KX = 0;
                    if (KX > Width - 1) KX = Width - 1;

                    // Загрузите данные каждого цветового канала в соответствующий массив фильтрации.
                    MEDMAS_R[index] = rgb_in[KY][KX].rgbtRed;
                    MEDMAS_G[index] = rgb_in[KY][KX].rgbtGreen;
                    MEDMAS_B[index] = rgb_in[KY][KX].rgbtBlue;

                    index++;
                }
            }

            // Примените сортировку к каждому массиву фильтрации.
            bubbleSort(MEDMAS_R, size);
            bubbleSort(MEDMAS_G, size);
            bubbleSort(MEDMAS_B, size);

            // Присвойте значение медианы (центрального элемента) из каждого массива фильтрации
            // соответствующему каналу в выходном изображении.
            rgb_out[Y][X].rgbtRed = MEDMAS_R[size / 2];
            rgb_out[Y][X].rgbtGreen = MEDMAS_G[size / 2];
            rgb_out[Y][X].rgbtBlue = MEDMAS_B[size / 2];
        }
    }

    delete[] MEDMAS_R;
    delete[] MEDMAS_G;
    delete[] MEDMAS_B;
    MEDMAS_R = nullptr;
    MEDMAS_G = nullptr;
    MEDMAS_B = nullptr;

    double time_stop = omp_get_wtime();

    return (time_stop - time_start) * 1000;
}
```

Я это пытался сделать, но у меня сортировка была медленнее последовательной, а иногда и вообще неправильно сортировала.

```
double MedianFilterBMPShellParall(RGBTRIPLE** rgb_in, RGBTRIPLE** rgb_out, int Width, int Height, int RW, int RH, int theards = 1) {
    double time_start = omp_get_wtime();

    int size = ((RH * 2) + 1) * ((RW * 2) + 1);

    // Зарезервируйте память для массивов фильтрации.
    unsigned char* MEDMAS_R = new unsigned char[size];
    unsigned char* MEDMAS_G = new unsigned char[size];
    unsigned char* MEDMAS_B = new unsigned char[size];


        // Перебираете изображение с шагом 1.
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(theards) shared(rgb_in, rgb_out, MEDMAS_R, MEDMAS_G, MEDMAS_B)

    for (int Y = 0; Y < Height; Y++) {
        for (int X = 0; X < Width; X++) {
            int index = 0;

            // Перебираете окно вокруг пикселя для апертуры фильтра медианы.
            for (int DY = -RH; DY <= RH; DY++) {
                int KY = Y + DY;

                // Проверьте, находится ли Y в пределах изображения.
                if (KY < 0) KY = 0;
                if (KY > Height - 1) KY = Height - 1;

                for (int DX = -RW; DX <= RW; DX++) {
                    int KX = X + DX;

                    // Проверьте, находится ли X в пределах изображения.
                    if (KX < 0) KX = 0;
                    if (KX > Width - 1) KX = Width - 1;

                    // Загрузите данные каждого цветового канала в соответствующий массив фильтрации.
                    MEDMAS_R[index] = rgb_in[KY][KX].rgbtRed;
                    MEDMAS_G[index] = rgb_in[KY][KX].rgbtGreen;
                    MEDMAS_B[index] = rgb_in[KY][KX].rgbtBlue;

                    index++;
                }
            }

            // Примените сортировку к каждому массиву фильтрации.
            shellSortParall(MEDMAS_R, size, theards);
            shellSortParall(MEDMAS_G, size, theards);
            shellSortParall(MEDMAS_B, size, theards);

            // Присвойте значение медианы (центрального элемента) из каждого массива фильтрации
            // соответствующему каналу в выходном изображении.
            rgb_out[Y][X].rgbtRed = MEDMAS_R[size / 2];
            rgb_out[Y][X].rgbtGreen = MEDMAS_G[size / 2];
            rgb_out[Y][X].rgbtBlue = MEDMAS_B[size / 2];
        }
    }

    delete[] MEDMAS_R;
    delete[] MEDMAS_G;
    delete[] MEDMAS_B;
    MEDMAS_R = nullptr;
    MEDMAS_G = nullptr;
    MEDMAS_B = nullptr;

    double time_stop = omp_get_wtime();

    return (time_stop - time_start) * 1000;
}
```

```
double MedianFilterBMPQuickSortParall(RGBTRIPLE** rgb_in, RGBTRIPLE** rgb_out, int Width, int Height, int RW, int RH, int theards = 1) {
    double time_start = omp_get_wtime();

    int size = ((RH * 2) + 1) * ((RW * 2) + 1);

    // Зарезервируйте память для массивов фильтрации.
    unsigned char* MEDMAS_R = new unsigned char[size];
    unsigned char* MEDMAS_G = new unsigned char[size];
    unsigned char* MEDMAS_B = new unsigned char[size];

#pragma omp parallel sections num_threads(theards)
    {
#pragma omp section
        {
            // Циклы по изображению
            for (int Y = 0; Y < Height; Y++) {
                for (int X = 0; X < Width; X++) {
                    int index = 0;

                    // Перебираете окно вокруг пикселя для апертуры фильтра медианы.
                    for (int DY = -RH; DY <= RH; DY++) {
                        int KY = Y + DY;

                        // Проверьте, находится ли Y в пределах изображения.
                        if (KY < 0) KY = 0;
                        if (KY > Height - 1) KY = Height - 1;

                        for (int DX = -RW; DX <= RW; DX++) {
                            int KX = X + DX;

                            // Проверьте, находится ли X в пределах изображения.
                            if (KX < 0) KX = 0;
                            if (KX > Width - 1) KX = Width - 1;

                            // Загрузите данные каждого цветового канала в соответствующий массив фильтрации.
                            MEDMAS_R[index] = rgb_in[KY][KX].rgbtRed;
                            

                            index++;
                        }
                    }

                    // Примените сортировку к каждому массиву фильтрации.
                    qSortParall(MEDMAS_R, size, theards);
                    

                    // Присвойте значение медианы (центрального элемента) из каждого массива фильтрации
                    // соответствующему каналу в выходном изображении.
                    rgb_out[Y][X].rgbtRed = MEDMAS_R[size / 2];
                    
                }
            }

            
        }

#pragma omp section
        {
            // Циклы по изображению
            for (int Y = 0; Y < Height; Y++) {
                for (int X = 0; X < Width; X++) {
                    int index = 0;

                    // Перебираете окно вокруг пикселя для апертуры фильтра медианы.
                    for (int DY = -RH; DY <= RH; DY++) {
                        int KY = Y + DY;

                        // Проверьте, находится ли Y в пределах изображения.
                        if (KY < 0) KY = 0;
                        if (KY > Height - 1) KY = Height - 1;

                        for (int DX = -RW; DX <= RW; DX++) {
                            int KX = X + DX;

                            // Проверьте, находится ли X в пределах изображения.
                            if (KX < 0) KX = 0;
                            if (KX > Width - 1) KX = Width - 1;

                            // Загрузите данные каждого цветового канала в соответствующий массив фильтрации.
                            MEDMAS_G[index] = rgb_in[KY][KX].rgbtGreen;

                            index++;
                        }
                    }

                    // Примените сортировку к каждому массиву фильтрации.
                    qSortParall(MEDMAS_G, size, theards);

                    // Присвойте значение медианы (центрального элемента) из каждого массива фильтрации
                    // соответствующему каналу в выходном изображении.
                    rgb_out[Y][X].rgbtGreen = MEDMAS_G[size / 2];
                }
            }

            
        }

#pragma omp section
        {
            // Циклы по изображению
            for (int Y = 0; Y < Height; Y++) {
                for (int X = 0; X < Width; X++) {
                    int index = 0;

                    // Перебираете окно вокруг пикселя для апертуры фильтра медианы.
                    for (int DY = -RH; DY <= RH; DY++) {
                        int KY = Y + DY;

                        // Проверьте, находится ли Y в пределах изображения.
                        if (KY < 0) KY = 0;
                        if (KY > Height - 1) KY = Height - 1;

                        for (int DX = -RW; DX <= RW; DX++) {
                            int KX = X + DX;

                            // Проверьте, находится ли X в пределах изображения.
                            if (KX < 0) KX = 0;
                            if (KX > Width - 1) KX = Width - 1;

                            // Загрузите данные каждого цветового канала в соответствующий массив фильтрации.
                            
                            MEDMAS_B[index] = rgb_in[KY][KX].rgbtBlue;

                            index++;
                        }
                    }

                    // Примените сортировку к каждому массиву фильтрации.
                    
                    qSortParall(MEDMAS_B, size, theards);

                    // Присвойте значение медианы (центрального элемента) из каждого массива фильтрации
                    // соответствующему каналу в выходном изображении.
                    
                    rgb_out[Y][X].rgbtBlue = MEDMAS_B[size / 2];
                }
            }

            
        }
    }

    delete[] MEDMAS_R;
    delete[] MEDMAS_G;
    delete[] MEDMAS_B;
    MEDMAS_R = nullptr;
    MEDMAS_G = nullptr;
    MEDMAS_B = nullptr;

    double time_stop = omp_get_wtime();

    return (time_stop - time_start) * 1000;
}
```

Comment: А отсортировать три массива в трёх отдельных потоках недостаточно? Параллельная сортировка не так чтобы ой-ёй-ёй превосходит однопоточную. Да и сортировать массив char не сказать, что выдающаяся идея.

Comment: @Ddd, нужно две реализации распараллеливания, допустим вы предложили первый вариант, но нужен ещё второй; нужно распараллелить не сортировку а функцию медианной фильтрации; это не моя прихоть, а условия задания

Comment: 1. Сортировка там вообще не нужна, как я понял. Вам нужна медиана распределения, это другая задача, решаемая без сортировки. 2. Сортировка массива char и нахождение  медианы делаются подсчётом, очень быстро. 3. Разбейте изображение на квадратики и обрабатывайте их параллельно, какие проблемы-то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я разобрался и написал две параллельные реализации медианной фильтрации

```
double MedianFilterBMPShellParall(RGBTRIPLE** rgb_in, RGBTRIPLE** rgb_out, int Width, int Height, int RW, int RH, int threads = 1) {
    double time_start = omp_get_wtime();
    omp_set_num_threads(threads);
    int size = ((RH * 2) + 1) * ((RW * 2) + 1);



#pragma omp parallel for
    for (int Y = 0; Y < Height; Y++) {
        unsigned char* MEDMAS_R = new unsigned char[size];
        unsigned char* MEDMAS_G = new unsigned char[size];
        unsigned char* MEDMAS_B = new unsigned char[size];
        for (int X = 0; X < Width; X++) {
            int index = 0;

            for (int DY = -RH; DY <= RH; DY++) {
                int KY = Y + DY;

                if (KY < 0) KY = 0;
                if (KY > Height - 1) KY = Height - 1;

                for (int DX = -RW; DX <= RW; DX++) {
                    int KX = X + DX;

                    if (KX < 0) KX = 0;
                    if (KX > Width - 1) KX = Width - 1;

                    MEDMAS_R[index] = rgb_in[KY][KX].rgbtRed;
                    MEDMAS_G[index] = rgb_in[KY][KX].rgbtGreen;
                    MEDMAS_B[index] = rgb_in[KY][KX].rgbtBlue;

                    index++;
                }
            }

            shellSort(MEDMAS_R, size);
            shellSort(MEDMAS_G, size);
            shellSort(MEDMAS_B, size);

            
            rgb_out[Y][X].rgbtRed = MEDMAS_R[size / 2];
            rgb_out[Y][X].rgbtGreen = MEDMAS_G[size / 2];
            rgb_out[Y][X].rgbtBlue = MEDMAS_B[size / 2];
        }
        delete[] MEDMAS_R;
        MEDMAS_R = nullptr;
        delete[] MEDMAS_G;
        MEDMAS_G = nullptr;
        delete[] MEDMAS_B;
        MEDMAS_B = nullptr;
    }


    double time_stop = omp_get_wtime();

    return (time_stop - time_start) * 1000;
}
```

```
double MedianFilterBMPQuickSortParall(RGBTRIPLE** rgb_in, RGBTRIPLE** rgb_out, int Width, int Height, int RW, int RH, int threads = 1) {
    double time_start = omp_get_wtime();
    omp_set_num_threads(threads);

    int size = ((RH * 2) + 1) * ((RW * 2) + 1);

#pragma omp parallel sections
    {
#pragma omp section
        {
            for (int Y = 0; Y < Height; Y++) {
                unsigned char* MEDMAS_R = new unsigned char[size];
                for (int X = 0; X < Width; X++) {
                    int index = 0;

                    for (int DY = -RH; DY <= RH; DY++) {
                        int KY = Y + DY;

                        if (KY < 0) KY = 0;
                        if (KY > Height - 1) KY = Height - 1;

                        for (int DX = -RW; DX <= RW; DX++) {
                            int KX = X + DX;

                            if (KX < 0) KX = 0;
                            if (KX > Width - 1) KX = Width - 1;

                            MEDMAS_R[index] = rgb_in[KY][KX].rgbtRed;
                            

                            index++;
                        }
                    }

                    quickSort(MEDMAS_R, size);
                    

                    rgb_out[Y][X].rgbtRed = MEDMAS_R[size / 2];
                    
                }
                delete[] MEDMAS_R;
                MEDMAS_R = nullptr;
            }

            
        }

#pragma omp section
        {
            for (int Y = 0; Y < Height; Y++) {
                unsigned char* MEDMAS_G = new unsigned char[size];
                for (int X = 0; X < Width; X++) {
                    int index = 0;

                    for (int DY = -RH; DY <= RH; DY++) {
                        int KY = Y + DY;

                        if (KY < 0) KY = 0;
                        if (KY > Height - 1) KY = Height - 1;

                        for (int DX = -RW; DX <= RW; DX++) {
                            int KX = X + DX;

                            if (KX < 0) KX = 0;
                            if (KX > Width - 1) KX = Width - 1;

                            MEDMAS_G[index] = rgb_in[KY][KX].rgbtGreen;

                            index++;
                        }
                    }

                    quickSort(MEDMAS_G, size);

                    rgb_out[Y][X].rgbtGreen = MEDMAS_G[size / 2];
                }
                delete[] MEDMAS_G;
                MEDMAS_G = nullptr;
            }

            
        }

#pragma omp section
        {
            for (int Y = 0; Y < Height; Y++) {
                unsigned char* MEDMAS_B = new unsigned char[size];
                for (int X = 0; X < Width; X++) {
                    int index = 0;

                    for (int DY = -RH; DY <= RH; DY++) {
                        int KY = Y + DY;

                        if (KY < 0) KY = 0;
                        if (KY > Height - 1) KY = Height - 1;

                        for (int DX = -RW; DX <= RW; DX++) {
                            int KX = X + DX;

                            if (KX < 0) KX = 0;
                            if (KX > Width - 1) KX = Width - 1;

                            
                            MEDMAS_B[index] = rgb_in[KY][KX].rgbtBlue;

                            index++;
                        }
                    }

                    
                    quickSort(MEDMAS_B, size);

                    
                    rgb_out[Y][X].rgbtBlue = MEDMAS_B[size / 2];
                }
                delete[] MEDMAS_B;
                MEDMAS_B = nullptr;
            }

            
        }
    }

    
    
    
    

    double time_stop = omp_get_wtime();

    return (time_stop - time_start) * 1000;
}
```